# how to call click event of class file from user control by using c#

Tags: c#

I had created one user control and one class file, The user control contain save button. When user click save button then i want call the Insert() using ItemClickedEventHandler from infocore class file please help me.

C#: User Control

```
public partial class toolbar : UserControl
{
    public delegate void ItemClickedEventHandler(System.Object sender, ItemClickEventArgs     e);
    public toolbar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        inf = new IAToolBar.infocore();
    }
    public event ItemClickedEventHandler ItemClicked;


    public class ItemClickEventArgs
    {
        public string flag;
        public ItemClickEventArgs(string flg)
        {
            flag = flg;
        }
    }

    private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemClicked != null)
        {
            ItemClicked(sender, new ItemClickEventArgs("Save"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the piece of code, where you create an instance for `toolbar` class

Comment: i had already post my code. when user click on save button of user control I just want to call the save method of class file with passing the active form name as a parameter.

Comment: `save` method or `insert` method? btw, the `insert` methods takes the `Form` as input and not `string`. Is there something i didn't see?

Comment: Thank you for replay friends,
sorry there is Insert Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Subscribe to the event `ItemClicked` when you create an instance of `toolbar` class.

I don't get to see you entire code, here is a sample:

C#: infocore.cs - Assume you create your toolbar instance here

```
            //Creating toolbar object
            toolbar objToolBar = new toolbar();
            objToolBar.ItemClicked += new toolbar.ItemClickedEventHandler(objToolBar_ItemClicked);


            //Handler to ItemClicked Event 
            void objToolBar_ItemClicked(object sender, MainWindow.toolbar.ItemClickEventArgs e)
            {
                 //Call Insert Method From here
            }
```

Comment: @MaheshBhosale: Can you update your question, with C#: infocore.cs code that you have tried.

Comment: How are you creating the Form object? Do you create it at runtime? If yes then you should be able to pass it directly e.g.: `MyForm objForm = new MyForm(); SomeFunctionAcceptForm(objForm);